# Should I keep pg_xlog on the same disk as data if using disk snapshotting?

Tags: postgresql, backup, recovery, snapshot

We're running on EBS volumes on EC2.  We're interested in leveraging
EBS snapshotting for backups.  However, does this mean we'd need to
ensure our pg_xlog is on the same EBS volume as our data?

(I believe) the usual reasoning for separating pg_xlog onto a separate
volume is for performance.  However, if they are on different volumes,
the snapshots may be out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

Having the transaction log (pg_xlog) on separate storage can increase write performance on most RDBMS platforms. If yours is a (concurrent) write heavy application, you may see a performance benefit.

If the snapshots are not synchronous however, you could lose data from uncomitted transactions in the event of an unclean restart. I suppose in certain situations a [pg_resetxlog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgresetxlog.html) could be required after a failure.

You could look into [WAL archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup-online.html), or even techniques similar to [ZFS snapshotting](http://lethargy.org/~jesus/writes/postgresql-warm-standby-on-zfs-crack) if EBS snapshots have the same effective purpose.